# How do I open up a specific page in the windows help dialogue?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, linklabel

A lot of built in Windows applications will have links to pages in the windows help. Is there any way I can create a linklabel that will open up a Windows Help dialog to a specific page?

===EDIT===

Hmm... well I was hoping on it being for all operating systems, but if I had to choose one over the other it would be Win7.

So: How do I access a specific page in Windows Help in windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on different Windows versions, there are different Windows Help.  For example, the help system on Windows 7 behaves very differently than the one on Windows XP.

MSDN offered a primitive starting point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx.  Maybe you can refine the question a bit more specific to get it resolved more quickly.